# Efficient Replace Characters in a string from one array for another

Tags: c#, algorithm, unicode

The specific problem I have is that I have to replace the numbers in chemical formulae with the equivalent Unicode subscripts, so H2SO4 => H₂SO₄. (Those subscripts are not font adjustments, they are special unicode characters.)

So my initial cut was:

```
return unit.Replace("2", "₂").
            Replace("3", "₃").
            Replace("4", "₄").
            Replace("5", "₅").
            Replace("6", "₆").
            Replace("7", "₇");
```

Which works, but obviously isn't particularly efficient. Any suggestions for a more optimal algorithm?

Comment: How do you measure efficiency here? How big is your data set?

Comment: Well, you could iterate over the string, check if the character is a digit and replace it with the corresponding character.

Comment: @Rinecamo, this is C#, strings are immutable, the questioner would have to copy `unit` into a `StringBuilder` or similar. This may or may not be worth that cost, which is why Luc asked about the actual context of the problem.

Comment: Why is it *obviously isn't particularry efficient*? It looks pretty efficient to me. And I think unless you have a billion of strings, you will not see any performance problems.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I think @Rincecamo is suggesting looping through the characters in `unit`, as `string` is practically a `char` array.

Comment: @elolos, not in C#, no.

Comment: By obviously not efficient I meant that this takes six passes over the string rather than just one. I was thinking along the lines of the equivalent of the tr command in Unix.

Comment: @salvadordali It is very inefficient: first, you have to iterate the whole string for each of the replacement, in this case 6 times, second, strings are immutable, thus each of the replacements creates a new string.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I'm sure you're confused, `char c = "test"[2];` or `"test".ToCharArray()` are c# and the recommended way to get the characters of a `string` object. Just because strings are immutable, it doesn't change the fact that they are based on char arrays.

Comment: This is a simple case of Pre-Optimization.  Don't solve for performance if you don't have any hard statics you have a problem, instead write readable and maintainable code.

Comment: @elolos, you're absolutely right, I was more focused on the *mutable* side of the equation.

Comment: @erikphilips I very much agree that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" but there is also no need to write code which is inefficient per definition if you can easily prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

There are only 10 possible subscript characters that need replacement and most chemical formulas are not too long. For this reason, I think your implementation is not horribly inefficient and I would suggest benchmarking your code before trying to optimize it.

But here's my attempt to create a method that does what you need:

```
    public string ToSubscriptFormula(string input)
    {
        var characters = input.ToCharArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (characters[i])
            {
                case '2':
                    characters[i] = '₂';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    characters[i] = '₃';
                    break;
               // case statements omitted
            }
        }
        return new string(characters);
    }
```

I would recommend avoiding the use of `StringBuilder` unless you're appending a large amount of strings, as the overhead of creating an instance would actually make your code less efficient. See [this post by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) for a detailed explanation of when it should be used.

Also, given the limited number of case statements, I personally don't think using a `Dictionary<char,char>` would add any readability or performance benefit, but under different scenarios it might be useful to consider using one.

But if you really had to super-optimize your method, you could replace the case statement with the following code (thanks to [andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491553/1598534) for the suggestion):

```
public string ToSubscriptFormula(string input)
{
    var characters = input.ToCharArray();
    const int distance = '₀' - '0';    // distance of subscript from digit
    for (var i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
    {
        if(char.IsDigit(characters[i]))
        {
            characters[i] = (char) (characters[i] + distance);
        }
    }
    return new string(characters);
}
```

The trick here is that all subscript characters are successive and that casting an `int` to `char` will give you the corresponding character.

Finally, as @nwellnhof has suggested in the comments, `char.IsDigit()` would return true for some non-latin digit characters in the [Unicode Nd Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).
If your chemical formula contains such characters, the statement should be replaced with `c >= '0' && c<='9'`. This will probably be slightly faster than `char.IsDigit` but I'm not sure if it would make a difference in most practical scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Jon Skeet's post. I concur that the present use case is limited enough to dispense with the Dictionary. For me it boiled down to a matter of personal taste ;-) Working directly on the char array as you do is, IMHO, very efficient, and introduces no overhead of StringBuilder creation.

Comment: Ahh - your second version is nice (avoiding an map/array/switch of subscript chars altogether).

Comment: Thanks @andrew. This question increasingly seems like an interview question that we are collectively trying to answer. Wouldn't it be nice if the OP had a chance to benchmark all versions against their data set?

Comment: @elolos - It might well be an interview question (or just a curious OP - which I like). Better than homework questions though. OP should definitely stroke their curiosity by bench-marking all options, though I'd be surprised if direct array manipulation didn't outperform all of the "construction" options.

Comment: Agreed, it will be faster, provided the difference is significant enough to be measurable.

Comment: `Char.IsDigit` returns true [for every Unicode character in category Nd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example decimal digits in non-Latin scripts. Your code converts these characters to nonsensical values.

Comment: @nwellnhof True, but the OP has clearly defined his requirement to be that input strings have a very specific format. For a more generic algorithm, you would need to use my first example or something else.

Comment: @elolos I didn't mean to convert decimal digits from other scripts but to simply leave them alone, i. e. replace `Char.IsDigit(c)` width `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.

Comment: @nwellhof My point was that in this specific case the input string would be pre-validated and not include non-latin unicode digits. In the spirit of super-optimization, the condition you provide would be faster, but if performance is not an issue and non-latin scripts are not a consideration, I like the readablility of `char.IsDigit()`

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to do something like this:

```
    public string replace(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Dictionary<char, char> map = new Dictionary<char, char>();
        map.Add('2', '₂');
        map.Add('3', '₃');
        map.Add('4', '₄');
        map.Add('5', '₅');
        map.Add('6', '₆');
        map.Add('7', '₇');

        char tmp;

        foreach(char c in input)
        {
            if (map.TryGetValue(c, out tmp))
                sb.Append(tmp);
            else
                sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

The `Dictionary` is defined inside the method here for simplicity, but should be defined somewhere else in scope.

So, very simply, iterate the `input` string only once. For every character, find the matching Dictionary entry if it exists, and append either that or the original character to a `StringBuilder` in order to avoid creating multiple string objects.

Comment: While I don't mind a downvote, I'd really like to understand why it was given. If you feel my answer was wrong or misleading, at least have the decency, or courage, of explaining yourself.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I could imagine it's because your code doesn't compile. It's a trivial fix, but that might be it.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the catch... that's what happens when you renames variables in the SO editor, not in VS ;-)

Comment: No worries. You should use LINQPad for your SO coding. It's a very useful tool and will speed up your "scratchpad" style of coding.

Comment: Yeah, I have it, I just never think of using it \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was what about formulae with balancing prefix numbers:

E.g. 2H₂(g) + O₂(g) → 2H₂O(g)

Presumably you don't want this to replace the leading numbers?

Also, I'm not sure why it is mentioned above that only 8 digits (or even only 6 digits) need replacement - aren't all digits required (0-9)? Sure, you don't have 0 and 1 by themselves, but you need them for, e.g., 10.

Anyway, notwithstanding the above (which I didn't attempt to implement since it wasn't the question), avoiding StringBuilder and operating on a char array seemed to make sense, and I preferred to avoid a large switch statement.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SubscriptNums("C6H12O6"));
    }

    public static string SubscriptNums(string input)
    {       
        char[] replacementChars = { '₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉' };

        int zeroCharIndex = (int)'0';

        char[] inputCharArray = input.ToCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < inputCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inputCharArray[i] >= '0' && inputCharArray[i] <= '9')
            {
                inputCharArray[i] = replacementChars[(int)inputCharArray[i] - zeroCharIndex];
            }
        }

        return new string(inputCharArray);
    }
}
```

Edit 1 - removed magic number for numeric value of '0'.

Edit 2 - removed use of IsDigit.

Comment: I really like the `Char.IsDigit()` condition, but can you please explain how you came up with the "magic" number 48? Also, good point about the preceding numbers, but I think it's easy to do the check either within the method or before calling it

Comment: The magic 48 is probably 'naughty'. It's the value of the character '0'. I should make that clearer: see edit.

Comment: In the spirit of well and truly prematurely optimising, I probably also should have taken the intitialisation of the array of subscript characters, as well as the zeroCharIndex outside of the function (static readonly members of the class probably) to avoid their repeated creation for every call to this function. I'll leave it as is though. :)

Comment: `Char.IsDigit` returns true [for every Unicode character in category Nd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example decimal digits in non-Latin scripts. These characters will result in an out-of-bound array access in your code.

Comment: @nwellnhof - Thanks. Good catch. I've fixed it. I misinterpreted the MSDN documentation of that Unicode category.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the string and check each char. If it is to replace, append the according character to the StringBuilder. If not, just add the original character. This way, you only have to iterate over the string once, and not once for each replacement. Furthermore, as strings are immutable, each call of `String.Replace()` will create a new copy of the string for the result, which will  immediately be GC'ed again.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < unit.Length; i++) {
    switch(unit[i]) {
        case '2': sb.Append('₂'); break;
        case '3': sb.Append('₃'); break;
        ...
        default: sb.Append(unit[i]); break;
    }
}

output = sb.ToString();
```

You could also introduce some replacement dictionary, like Abdullah Nehir suggested

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>();
//put in the pairs
for (int i = 0; i < unit.Length; i++) {
    if (replacements.ContainsKey(unit[i]))
        sb.Append(replacement[unit[i]];
    else
        sb.Append(unit[i]);
}
```

Instead of accessing the values via index, you can also iterate the string with a foreach loop

```
foreach (char c in unit) {
   if (replacements.ContainsKey(c))
       sb.Append(replacements[c]);
   else
       sb.Append(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for some elegant code where you don't have to type `string.Replace` for each character, then this would help you:

```
    public static string Replace(string input)
    {
        char[] inputCharArr = input.ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in inputCharArr)
        {
            int intC = (int)c;
            //If the digit was a number ([0-9] are [48-57] in unicode),
            //replace the old char with the new char
            //(8272 when added to the unicode of [0-9] gives the desired result)
            if (intC > 47 && intC < 58)
                sb.Append((char)(intC + 8272));
            else sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

*See the edit history if you wonder what the comments are talking about.*

Comment: 1) Personally, I would not call a piece of code full of some magic constants elegant. Efficient, maybe, but not elegant or easy to maintain.  2) all of your approaches  only work for this very special case where you want to replace one contiguous block of characters with another block 3) your first piece of code is even less efficient as the OP's. You do a `string.replace` for each character to replace and iterate the string one additional time. 4) in your second approach every `+=` creates a new string which is also quite expensive

Comment: 5) in your third approach, you should use a `StringBuilder` instead of `List<char> lst` because that's what a `StringBuilder` is for.

Comment: @derpirscher; As for (1) and (2), I believe that's what the OP really wanted. As for (3), that's not right; I did test the speed for each piece of code. As for(4), you're right, and that's why I wrote `Replace3`. As for (5), I replaced the `List<char>` with a `StringBuilder` and it did work faster than all my above solutions, the answer will now be updated. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Sorry, but your first approach cannot be faster then the op's Code. You are doing the same number of string.replace, you are iterating the string one more time, you do an additional lookup in a List (i would suggest using a Set here) and you are checking each character in the string if it needs to be replaced. So you are looking at each character in the string 11 times, whereas the op's code uses 7 and most of the other answers only once.

Comment: I'm not only expecting how fast the code will be; I'm measuring it. See [this](http://rextester.com/XFMODA75562) and tell me what you think. ;)